# Не могу получить данные из session

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

сохраняю юзера `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);`
после чего хочу вывести его в jsp, но ничего не выводит

````
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Jsp Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ${session.getAttribute("user")}
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: А зачем у вас `session="false"?`

Comment: А если так `<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>`?